# Cassandra hangs with compaction and cleanup

Tags: cassandra-2.0

`Cassandra 2.1.5` is running on `Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u5 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
 # java -version
 java version "1.7.0_72"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

Cluster of 6 nodes. Queries from clients are working normally. But disk space is used  80-90% (for cassandra data). And compaction of large tables is hanging (and cleanup too) - without any errors. Up to node restart - after that compaction of small tables is working until started compaction of large table (> 50Gb) - from this moment `nodetool compactionstats` in "progress" and "completed" column is not changed and incrementing "pending tasks".

```
nodetool stop COMPACTION
```

is not solve this: check - what is cassandra do in this moment? Skip only big tables from compaction?
Joining new nodes, like compaction, is hangs...

Comment: please refer https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226119-Troubleshooting-hanging-repairs

Comment: No, i don't see any `AntiEntropy` or network errors... But i'll read datastax help center, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced a similar scenario with our 2.1.5 cassandra cluster of 4 nodes. There was no error but compaction is stuck and node was not able to process incoming requests. We took thread dump with jstack and then find the compaction thread which was hanged. Then, we killed it. After that, node continued its working as usual.